# RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed (build tools 19.0.2)

Tags: android, renderscript, build-tools

Here's my entire output:

```
02-26 09:55:50.410      625-640/com.vsco.cam E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: android.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed.
            at android.renderscript.ScriptC.<init>(ScriptC.java:61)
            at android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptCThunker.<init>(ScriptCThunker.java:39)
            at android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptC.<init>(ScriptC.java:62)
            at com.vsco.cam.utility.ScriptC_processing.<init>(ScriptC_processing.java:41)
            at com.vsco.cam.effects.EffectProcessor.initialize(EffectProcessor.java:67)
            at com.vsco.cam.LoadingAsyncTask.doInBackground(LoadingAsyncTask.java:24)
            at com.vsco.cam.LoadingAsyncTask.doInBackground(LoadingAsyncTask.java:16)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Here's a part of my build.gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportMode=true
    }
```

Prior to updating my build tools to 19.0.2, I was getting an rs for each error, which was fixed with the newest build tools version (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64110).  Now I'm completely at a loss as to why this won't run on non-4.4 phones (phones that need backwards compat., aka, the support library).  Is this the same issue as the rs for each, or am I just missing something?

Seems to be failing right here, within the ScriptC.java file:

```
protected ScriptC(RenderScript rs, Resources resources, int resourceID) {
        super(0, rs);
        int id = internalCreate(rs, resources, resourceID);
        if (id == 0) {
            throw new RSRuntimeException("Loading of ScriptC script failed.");
        }
        setID(id);
    }
```

ScriptC_processing: 41:

```
 public  ScriptC_processing(RenderScript rs, Resources resources, int id) {
        super(rs, resources, id);
        __ALLOCATION = Element.ALLOCATION(rs);
        __SCRIPT = Element.SCRIPT(rs);
        __U32_2 = Element.U32_2(rs);
        __SAMPLER = Element.SAMPLER(rs);
        __F32_2 = Element.F32_2(rs);
        __I32 = Element.I32(rs);
        __F32 = Element.F32(rs);
        __U8_4 = Element.U8_4(rs);
    }
```

Edit: Looks like the id is being set here:

```
protected ScriptC(RenderScript rs, Resources resources, int resourceID) {
    super(0, rs);

    if (rs.isNative) {
        RenderScriptThunker rst = (RenderScriptThunker)rs;
        ScriptCThunker s = new ScriptCThunker(rst, resources, resourceID);
        mT = s;
        return;
    }

    int id = internalCreate(rs, resources, resourceID);
    if (id == 0) {
        throw new RSRuntimeException("Loading of ScriptC script failed.");
    }
    setID(id);
}
```

Comment: I see that, but where does that get set?

Comment: And why does this only happen on non 4-4 devices?  That would make it seem like a support lib issue.

Comment: it does not get set in the code that you included in the question. Take a look at `ScriptC_processing.java:41`

Comment: Added into the original question above.

Comment: add a breakpoint at the first line of this method and check the value of `id`

Comment: Added a breakpoint and the id is in fact not null (or 0).  Any other ideas?

Comment: id cannot be null because it is just an int. this `super(rs, resources, id);` is a constructor that is defined in your project?

Comment: Thanks for helping get to the bottom of this, and for the quick replies.  I'm assuming this is where the error is stemming from (see last code insert in question):

Comment: You should not be using a renderscriptTargetAPI of 19. It can only be 18 for the support library.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Stephen Hines' comment, the reason this was breaking was due to my target api being set to 19.

Comment: It actually has nothing to do with bitcode encoding. The issue is in the support library itself (and how it chooses to load the bitcode/Script). If you target API 19, we embed a header that says it is 19. The Java/native code in the support library then mishandles this. Hopefully we can make this error more explicit in the future, but all of the docs specifically call out API 17 for using the support library today.