# Renderscript not working for Adt bundle

Tags: android, adt, renderscript

I'm using the Android ADT bundle on Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm trying to write an app that uses RenderScript.

I've placed a .rs file in the package folder and it looks as follows:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.test)

void root(const uchar4 *in, uchar4 *out, uint32_t x, uint32_t y){

    out->r = rsRand(255); 
    out->g = rsRand(255); 
    out->b = rsRand(255); 

}
```

However I'm getting the following errors:

```
error: Compute kernel root() targeting SDK levels 11-13 may not skip (on line 4)
error: missing "#pragma rs java_package_name(com.foo.bar)" in source file (on line 10)
error: missing pragma for version in source file (on line 10)
```

Can anybody please help me figure out this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem when trying to build the HelloCompute renderscript example. I use Eclipse, and after examining the error messages in the Problems window, I noted that they dealt with version numbers. So I changed the version numbers in the project.properties file as follows:

```
target=android-20
renderscript.target=20
renderscript.support.mode=true
sdk.buildtools=20
```

After this, the pragma errors went away and the project built successfully.

Comment: Correction. Set the renderscript target API  to 18 instead of 20: renderscript.target=18. Otherwise you'll get a runtime error "loading of Scriptc script failed". See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049712/rsruntimeexception-loading-of-scriptc-script-failed-build-tools-19-0-2)